# How can I schedule a Nandroid backup?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup, nandroid, automation

Is it possible to schedule a Nandroid backup for a particular time on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S2 running CM9 and the Siyah Kernel? How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an automatic nandroid backup using ROM Manager ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) / [paid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager.license)).

open the app - go to settings and select Automatic Backup.  You can select the time and frequency of the backups in the following screens.

Comment: I've read that ROM Manager has issues with the S2. Is that correct?

Comment: I've not heard of any issues with the s2 and Rom Manager.  My girlfriend uses it on her S2 without any issues, although I'm aware that is anecdotal and not empirical.  It may be worth trying to backup and restore to see if you run in to any problems now rather than relying on it for it to fail.

Comment: I did try to schedule a backup, but it didn't work. The schedule did initiate, but a long list of errors was thrown up. I think it could be because I'm on the Siyah Kernel which uses a customised version of ClockworkMod Recovery.